# Web service security issue

Tags: php, iphone, web-services

I have developed a set of web services for iphone app (used for magaine purchase) but now i found a serious security problem.

1. one user logged the web service call using some tool in his iphone
       device.
2. now he can call web service for purchase with out actually
           purchasing.

please help me to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a secure unique string/number upon payment authorisation that must be used in the script to add a magazine to that account only. Once the call has been made, disable the key.

This way it will fail when people randomly call the 'add magazine' web service.

Comment: Generate the ID straight after the call to the payment service succeeds (where you are forwarding to the web-service).

Comment: what will happen if he call the web service for generating id and then he call the purchase web service

Comment: Good question, now I'm not too sure on the payment API for iTunes but is there anyway to wrap it inside a web-service call? For example, call PayForMagazine{check payment details, if true generate ID then forward to subscription web service}, this way the only way to generate an ID will be with a valid payment.